# JSP EL numberOfItems property results in NumberFormatException

Tags: jsp

I believe that the proper way in JSP EL to determine the length of an array attribute or the size of a List attribute is to use the `numberOfItems` property like so:

```
<c:if test="${subpages.numberOfItems > 1}">
  ...
</c:if>
```

At least, this is what is shown in, e.g., the [Java 7 EL examples](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/jsf-el008.htm#BNAIM), but when I attempt to use this I get:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "numberOfItems"
```

My `subpages` attribute is a List, so if I replace numberOfItems by the method call size(), the JSP works as intended. Any idea why use of `numberOfItems` is not working? Is there is a better way to test the size of an array or list?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You misinterpreted. From  [Java 7 EL examples](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/jsf-el008.htm)

```
${sessionScope.cart.numberOfItems}
```

The value of the `numberOfItems` **property of** the session-scoped **attribute** named **cart**. Emphasize mine.

`numberOfItems` is the property defined for the attribute `cart` and it is accessed through session.

---

> Is there is a better way to test the size of an array or list?

Yes. Use [JSTL functions](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnalg.html).

```
 <%@ taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" %>
  ....
  <c:if test="${fn:length(subpages) > 1}">
    ...
  </c:if>
```

Although the [java.util.Collection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html) interface defines a size method, it does not conform to the JavaBeans component design pattern for properties and so cannot be accessed by using the JSP expression language. The length function can be applied to any collection supported by the [c:forEach](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/c/forEach.html) and returns the length of the collection. When applied to a String, it returns the number of characters in the string.

#### Related link

- [JSTL functions](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/products/products/jsp/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/fn/tld-summary.html)

Comment: Of course you are right, and the Java 7 EL example text is clear now in retrospect. What threw me off was the [Java 6 EL Overview](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/gjddd/index.html) text which reads "For example, ... an EL expression that compares 0 with the number of items in the session-scoped bean named cart." Thanks @Aniket.

Comment: @user3046255 : In Java [EE 6 EL examples](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnaim.html) is same table as of Java EE 7. This is just example they have shown. You can declare one such `noOfItems` variable in Bean add objects of bean class to list and then you can and access that variable.